# How to realign items in a media query using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to realign my 3 columns of test in id="articles" using a media query. I would like to move them so that they are vertically and not horizontally. I have tried using flexbox, but it does not fix my problem. Do you know if it is possible to do that with flexbox? If not, how could I do it?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'kinder';
  src: url('kindergarten.ttf');
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  aside {
    display: none;
  }
  #articles {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}


/* Eléments principaux de la page */

body {
  background: url('back.jpg');
  font-family: 'kinder', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #181818;
}

#bloc_page {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Header */

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#titre {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#titre div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: 25px;
}


/* Body */

aside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url(ban.jpg);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#articles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#articles h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>CV de Jules Raymond</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bloc_page">
    <header>
      <div id="titre">
        <h1>Jules Raymond</h1>

        <div>
          <a href="moi.jpeg"> <img src="moi_mini.jpg" alt="Une photo de Jules Raymond" title="Cliquez pour agrandir" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h3>Etudiant à l'université de Californie-Berkeley</h3>
    </header>


    <section>
      <aside></aside>

      <div id="articles">
        <div id="experience">
          <h3>Mon experience</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>De 1992 à 2004: naissance et école primaire</li>
            <li>De 2004 à 2010: école secondaire (high scool)</li>
            <li>De 2010 jusqu'à présent: étudiant universitaire</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="competences">
          <h3>Mes competances</h3>
          <ol>
            <li>HTML & CSS (en procès)</li>
            <li>PHP & MySql (avancé)</li>
            <li>C (expert)</li>
          </ol>
        </div>

        <div id="formation">
          <h3>Ma formation</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>J'ai appris sur <a href="http://openclassrooms.com/" title="Cliquez pour découvrir!">OpenClassroom</a>.</li>
            <li>J'ai posé mes questions sur <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" title="Cliquez pour découvrir encore!">StackOverFlow</a>.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is okay with your code. Except one major mistake - Media queries should **ALWAYS** be written **AFTER** your code.

Your code right now:

```
@media query;
CSS;
```

What it should look like in order for it to work:

```
CSS;
@media query;
```

Media queries are the way of telling a browser - this is my CSS so far, when the site is displayed at * width, please apply these new styles to it. This is the base idea behind cascading stylesheets.